# MVC Model Binding - Validate EVERY property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have some generic validation I want blanket applied to every string property on every model.  I'm looking at subclassing the `DefaultModelBinder` and adding logic by overridding the `BindProperty` method.  Would this be an appropriate thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing the `DefaultModelBinder` and overriding `BindProperty` is working well for me.  Calling the base.BindProperty ensures that the model's property is set, and I can then evaluate it for the global validation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Write your own custom modelbinder.
2. Use Reflection to get all properties
3. Check if the property is of type `string`
4. Get the value of the property using reflection
5. Run your custom validation and add validation errors to the `ModelState`

#### Sample

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(bindingContext.Model.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
           if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string)) 
           {
               var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(bindingContext.Model);
               // validate
               // append to ModelState if validation failed
               bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(propertyInfo.Name, "Validation Failed");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Use the ModelBinder

```
public ActionResult MyActionMethod([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder ))] ModelType model)
{
  // ModelState.IsValid is false if validation fails
}
```

#### More Information

- [ASP.NET MVC Custom Model Binding](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584)
- [MSDN - Type.GetProperties Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx)
- [MSDN - PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx)
- [MSDN - ModelStateDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Why do you recommend I write my own as opposed to subclassing the default one?  Also I don't want to require everyone that they add an attribute in every action method to trigger the behavior.  It should happen by default.